# Why can Ubuntu 17.10 not connect to internet unless connected via windscribe-cli?

Tags: networking, 17.10, vpn

I have installed windscribe-cli VPN. However, I cannot disconnect, and use the internet. Attempted thus far:

- windscribe disconnect
- sudo windscribe stop
- windscribe firewall off
- windscribe protocol tcp

Nothing allows me to connect to the local network. This, in and of itself, would not be a problem. However, I have local resources (printers, drives, library log-in) that cannot be accessed otherwise.

What have I missed?

UPDATE: [ip route] produced the following output disconnected:

```
default via 140.228.22.1 dev wlp5s0 proto static metric 20600 
140.228.22.0/24 dev wlp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 140.228.22.48 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp5s0 scope link metric 1000
```

and this when connected:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.115.44.1 dev tun0 
default via 140.228.22.1 dev wlp5s0 proto static metric 20600 
10.115.44.0/23 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.115.44.24 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.115.44.1 dev tun0 
140.228.22.0/24 dev wlp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 140.228.22.48 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp5s0 scope link metric 1000
207.189.25.3 via 140.228.22.1 dev wlp5s0
```

In addition, `sudo service networking restart` has not worked, `sudo ip route flush cache` had failed, and restarting the wireless card had not helped. I cannot connect to the internet without VPN.

Comment: AFAIK, VPNs change yout routiong tables so that ALL traffic goes through the VPN. It sounds like however you're stopping `windscribe` is not restoring your routing tables. Start by looking at `ip route`

Comment: @waltinator I have updated the question with output from `ip route`.